# Unable to fetch data for multiple posts using LinkedIn Share Stats API

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn Community Management APIs and I'm encountering an issue when trying to fetch data for multiple posts (for single post I am able to fetch data) using the Share Stats API. Here's the API endpoint I'm using:

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:2414183&ugcPosts[0]=urn:li:ugcPost:1000000&ugcPosts[1]=urn:li:ugcPost:1000001`

The problem is that I'm not able to retrieve the desired data. I have confirmed that the organizationalEntity parameter is set correctly, but when I include multiple ugcPosts values, I don't get the expected results.

Can someone help me understand what could be causing this issue and how to fetch data for multiple posts using the Share Stats API? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.